# no package matching is available in ansible version 2.7.10

Tags: ansible

Can't install the packages in the virtual machine with ansible. Error: No package matching is available

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root
  #tasks:
  # - name: test connection
  #   ping:
  #   remote_user: 192.168.33.10
  #sudo: yes
  tasks:
    #- name: make sure apache is running
    #  service: name=httpd state=running
    - name: General | Instalacion de paquetes requeridos.

      action: apt pkg={{ item }} state=present
      with_items:
         -unzip
         -mysql-server
         -mysql-client
         -apache2
         -php-mysql
         -php-apc
         -php-xmlrpc
         -php-soap
         -php-gd
         -php
         -python-mysqldb

##
# Configuracion de Apache2
##

    - name: Apache2 | Habilitar módulos
      action: command a2enmod rewrite vhost_alias

##
# Reinicio de servicios
##

    - name: Restart Apache
      action: service name=apache2 state=restarted
```

Is there another option to do it, or how do I know what packages use', I tried installing a few packages at one, but failed too.

The complete error is:

PLAY [webservers] **************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [192.168.33.10]

TASK [General | Instalacion de paquetes requeridos.] ***************************
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Invoking "apt" only once while using a loop via 
squash_actions is deprecated. Instead of using a loop to supply multiple items 
and specifying `pkg: "{{ item }}"`, please use `pkg: '-unzip -mysql-server 
-mysql-client -apache2 -php-mysql -php-apc -php-xmlrpc -php-soap -php-gd -php 
-python-mysqldb'` and remove the loop. This feature will be removed in version 
2.11. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting 
deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
failed: [192.168.33.10] (item=[u'-unzip -mysql-server -mysql-client -apache2 -php-mysql -php-apc -php-xmlrpc -php-soap -php-gd -php -python-mysqldb']) => {"changed": false, "item": ["-unzip -mysql-server -mysql-client -apache2 -php-mysql -php-apc -php-xmlrpc -php-soap -php-gd -php -python-mysqldb"], "msg": "No package matching '-unzip -mysql-server -mysql-client -apache2 -php-mysql -php-apc -php-xmlrpc -php-soap -php-gd -php -python-mysqldb' is available"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/guillermo/Documentos/vagrant-ansible/playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.33.10              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Comment: Can you please include the complete error message in your question?

Comment: I edit the post, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid YAML.  A YAML list item is denoted by:

```
-<space><item>
```

Whereas you have:

```
-<item>
```

This is just a literal string.  If you look at the error, you'll see the apt is trying to install packages with names like `-unzip` and `-mysql-server`, etc, which of course don't exist.  You need to write your task like this:

```
- name: General | Instalacion de paquetes requeridos.
  action: apt pkg={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
     - unzip
     - mysql-server
     - mysql-client
     - apache2
     - php-mysql
     - php-apc
     - php-xmlrpc
     - php-soap
     - php-gd
     - php
     - python-mysqldb
```

But if you take another look at the error, you'll see:

> Invoking "apt" only once while using a loop via squash_actions is deprecated...

It looks as if you've been learning Ansible based on outdated information.  You should modernize your syntax to look like this:

```
- name: General | Instalacion de paquetes requeridos.
  apt:
    name: "{{ packages }}"
    state: installed
  vars:
    packages:
       - unzip
       - mysql-server
       - mysql-client
       - apache2
       - php-mysql
       - php-apc
       - php-xmlrpc
       - php-soap
       - php-gd
       - php
       - python-mysqldb
```

Comment: thanks a lot, now I am getting other errors, but the first is gone and I don't have any warnings